# How to show function calls on a C++ class member variable on a UML sequence diagram?

Tags: c++, uml, sequence-diagram

I am trying to figure out how to depict the following function on a UML sequence diagram:

```
void NodeGraph::notify_graph_change()
{
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> graph_changed_lock(graph_mutex_);
    bool bad_ptr_encountered = false;
    for (auto & event_wptr : graph_events_) {
      auto event_ptr = event_wptr.lock();
      if (event_ptr) {
        event_ptr->set();
      } else {
        bad_ptr_encountered = true;
      }
    }
    if (bad_ptr_encountered) {
      graph_events_.erase(
        std::remove_if(graph_events_.begin(), graph_events_.end(),
          [](const rclcpp::Event::WeakPtr & wptr) {
            return wptr.expired();
          }), graph_events_.end());
      graph_users_count_.store(graph_events_.size());
    }
  }
  graph_cv_.notify_all();
  auto & node_gc = node_base_->get_notify_guard_condition();
  try {
    node_gc.trigger();
  } catch (const rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError & ex) {
    throw std::runtime_error(
            std::string("failed to notify wait set on graph change: ") + ex.what());
  }
}
```

Specifically the calls like **graph_events_.erase**(), **graph_cv_.notify_all**() or **node_gc.trigger**(). If I add separate lifelines for such member variables, how can I show that their lifelines are related/bound to the NodeGraph class instance lifeline, and ensure the right ordering of actions on the time axis?

Comment: [Are you asking about these green bars?](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/7ecba6de-09df-4c14-af49-51142cd79e04.png)

Comment: [Or these rectangular outlines?](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marcelo-Queiroz-4/publication/268276261/figure/fig4/AS:742856180383745@1554122123120/Sequence-diagram-of-a-periodic-event-exchange-cycle-Time-runs-downward-according-to-the.png)

Comment: Is your sequence diagram showing interactions between NodeGraph and other classes? If so, implementation details of NodeGraph seem counter-productive.

Comment: There may be indirect calls to other classes, e.g. graph_cv_.notify_all() could call functions  on some instances outside the NodeGraph class.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence diagram does not represent on its own the full system. It's just one possible scenario of interactions. The class diagram will show the structural relationships.

There is an easy way to highlight the relationship however: name the lifelines, e,g. `a:NodeGraph`, `a.graph_events_:Xyz` etc...

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility I did not think of, by giving the instances meanigful names. Thanks for the hint.